# How to convert a c++/Qt visual studio solution with multiple project to QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2015, qt-creator, qmake

I have a visual studio 2015 solution with multiple projects on it and I need to build it under Linux, so I used the QT plugin to create .pro file and export it to QtCreator. This worked fine for a single project but for a solution with multiple interdependent project I just couldn't find any option.
Also I tried creating a .pro file for each project to import each of them to QtCreator then create the inter-dependencies. but I couldn't find an option in QtCreator to add/import a sub-project, only creating a new one.

need your help, is there any one who've done that before?
Thanks

Comment: Can you build [using QtCreator dependencies](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-build-dependencies.html) always or do you need a commandline solution?

Comment: I tried that but I still don't get a single project (.sln - solution like)